# /sitemap.xml endpoint not working on production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

I have created a web site using the standard ASP.Net MVC 5 template with no authentication. I have added MVCSiteMapProvider from NuGet. On my dev machine the /sitemap.xml endpoint returns the correct sitemap once I add the UrlRoutingModule-4.0 to web.config. If I publish to Azure Web Sites the /sitemap.xml endpoint also works. However if I publish to my local hoster the /sitemap.xml endpoint returns a 404 - File or directory not found.

Any idea what I need to change / add to web.config to get the endpoint working?

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, this configuration is all that is required to make it function in MVC4/MVC5:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

But then, I don't have much of an idea why this line is required, a [contributor figured it out](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/124#issuecomment-12255144) and I added the solution to the NuGet package.

Comment: Just a quick update, turns out my hoster decided to put my site in the classic app pool. Once it was moved to the integrated app pool all worked fine.